# Jmeter - waiting for a web grid to load

Tags: testing, automation, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

So we are tasked with doing automation against one of our web applications that has a lot of Ajax calls. We can't seem to get the Test Recorder to work, so right now we are manually writing out those requests. There is a particular web grid that contains about 100 rows x 20 columns of data. We are trying to measure how long it takes to load up that grid. The response data doesn't have any information on the grid too. Do you guys have any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: So is there an error message? How exactly do you know the Test Recorder isn't working? Please edit your question to include all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) will not help too much as it generates **sequential** calls while [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests are **parallel**.
2. As per JMeter project main page:

   > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So I would recommend reconsidering your approach and use i.e. [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin in order to measure page loading time using a real browser instance. This way you will also be able to get extra information from the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API)

If for some reason WebDriver Sampler approach is not acceptable for you - make sure that JMeter sends the same requests as real browser does:

1. Capture requests which are being sent by JMeter and by the real browser using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) of [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
2. Compare the requests, identify the differences
3. Amend JMeter configuration until requests would be exactly the same (apart from dynamic values in cookies or parameters)

Also be aware that you can mimic AJAX requests parallel execution in JMeter using [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try your suggestion and let you know in a few days.